# Function that prints something to std::ostream and returns std::ostream?

Tags: c++, outputstream, ostream

I want to write a function that outputs something to a `ostream` that's passed in, and return the stream, like this:

```
std::ostream& MyPrint(int val, std::ostream* out) {
  *out << val;
  return *out;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    std::cout << "Value: " << MyPrint(12, &std::cout) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

It would be convenient to print the value like this and embed the function call in the output operator chain, like I did in `main()`.

It doesn't work, however, and prints this:

```
$ ./a.out
12Value: 0x6013a8
```

The desired output would be this:

```
Value: 12
```

How can I fix this? Do I have to define an `operator<<` instead?

**UPDATE:** Clarified what the desired output would be.

**UPDATE2:** Some people didn't understand why I would print a number like that, using a function instead of printing it directly. This is a simplified example, and in reality the function prints a complex object rather than an `int`.

Comment: Why are you passing the stream via a pointer rather than via  areference?

Comment: Maybe he's read the Google style guide, and bought into this "don't use non-const reference parameters" fashion that's going around.

Comment: Also, what's the point of not doing  `cout << "Value: " << 12;` like @Neil recommends? That seems to be the most straight forward solution.

Comment: @Neil and @onebyone: Yes, I started using the google style conventions.

Comment: @litb: Just printing '12' was just a toy example. In reality, I don't pass an int, but a more complicated data structure that has to be printed to the stream.

Comment: @dehmann Please stop using the google conventions. If you need reasons, there was a big discussion about this on the comp.lang.c++.moderated usenet newsgroup.

Comment: Re: UPDATE2 -- To print this complex object of yours, why not just define a new overloaded std::operator<< for that type, just like every other normal class uses?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can't fix the function. Nothing in the spec requires a compiler to evaluate a function call in an expression in any particular order with respect to some unrelated operator in the same expression. So without changing the calling code, you can't make `MyPrint()` evaluate after `std::cout << "Value: "`

Left-to-right order is mandated for expressions consisting of multiple consecutive << operators, so that will work. The point of operator<< returning the stream is that when operators are chained, the LHS of each one is supplied by the evaluation of the operator to its left.

You can't achieve the same thing with free function calls because they don't have a LHS. `MyPrint()` returns an object equal to `std::cout`, and so does `std::cout << "Value: "`, so you're effectively doing `std::cout << std::cout`, which is printing that hex value.

Since the desired output is:

```
Value: 12
```

the "right" thing to do is indeed to override operator<<. This frequently means you need to either make it a friend, or do this:

```
class WhateverItIsYouReallyWantToPrint {
    public:
    void print(ostream &out) const {
        // do whatever
    }
};

ostream &operator<<(ostream &out, const WhateverItIsYouReallyWantToPrint &obj) {
    obj.print(out);
}
```

If overriding `operator<<` for your class isn't appropriate, for example because there are multiple formats that you might want to print, and you want to write a different function for each one, then you should either give up on the idea of operator chaining and just call the function, or else write multiple classes that take your object as a constructor parameter, each with different operator overloads.

Comment: I know I always find it easier to break streams down into traditional function calls when I can't get my head around something so I thought I'd add this for the OP in case it helps them too. Hope you don't mind. I think I'm right in saying the std::cout line basically boils down to

    cout.operator<<( "Value: " ).operator<<( MyPrint(12, &std::cout ) ).operator<<( std::endl );

which might be an easier way of visualising what this answer says.

Comment: I updated the question; it says now that the desired output would be Value: 12.

Comment: @SteveJessop You've probably forgotten to put `return` statement at the end of `operator<<` implementation: `return out;`.

Answer (score 6):

You want to make MyPrint a class with friend operator<<:

```
class MyPrint
{
public:
    MyPrint(int val) : val_(val) {}
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const MyPrint& mp) 
    {
        os << mp.val_;
        return os;
    }
private:
    int val_;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::cout << "Value: " << MyPrint(12) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This method requires you to insert the MyPrint object into the stream of your choice. If you REALLY need the ability to change which stream is active, you can do this:

```
class MyPrint
{
public:
    MyPrint(int val, std::ostream& os) : val_(val), os_(os) {}
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& dummy, const MyPrint& mp) 
    {
        mp.os_ << mp.val_;
        return os_;
    }
private:
    int val_;
    std::ostream& os_
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::cout << "Value: " << MyPrint(12, std::cout) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Except that this does not do what was asked for.

Comment: Well, to start with, it doesn't compile.

Comment: Oops. Bad copy/paste. Thanks for catching.

Comment: It doesn't have to be a friend; it only uses public methods of the std::ostream.

Comment: Make it a template class and add a template function to create it and its perfect.

Comment: @Max Lybbert: It does access a private member variable?

Comment: This is exactly how I would have answered this question

Comment: Sorry, "it only uses public methods of the std::ostream, so it doesn't need to be a friend of the std::ostream; since it's a method of MyPrint it already has access to private methods and variables of MyPrint and doesn't need to be a friend of MyPrint either (plus a class can't be a friend of itself)."

Comment: @Max Lybbert. 1) What do you mean by *"method"*? 2) The function `operator<<` in his code is *not* a member of the class. Removing the friend keyword would make it a member, but would make the code invalid, because a member `operator<<` must have one parameter only. It's called a *"friend definition"*.

Comment: I've put some explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/991518/c-how-do-i-call-a-friend-template-function-defined-inside-a-class/991870#991870

Comment: Thanks for the correction.  As you can see from my answer, I've generally defined these as non-member functions.

Answer (score 4):

You have two options.  The first, using what you already have is:

```
std::cout << "Value: ";
MyPrint(12, &std::cout);
std::cout << std::endl;
```

The other, which is more C++-like, is to replace `MyPrint()` with the appropriate `std::ostream& operator<<`.  There's already one for `int`, so I'll do one just a tad more complex:

```
#include <iostream>

struct X {
    int y;
};

// I'm not bothering passing X as a reference, because it's a
// small object
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const X x)
{
    return os << x.y;
}

int main()
{
    X x;
    x.y = 5;
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to do what you're expecting there because of the order the functions are evaluated in.

Is there any particular reason you need to write directly to the ostream like that? If not, just have MyPrint return a string. If you want to use a stream inside MyPrint to generate the output, just use a strstream and return the result.

Answer (score 0):

First, there is no reason not to pass in the `ostream` by reference rather than by a pointer:

```
std::ostream& MyPrint(int val, std::ostream& out) {
  out << val;
  return out;
}
```

If you really don't want to use `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, TYPE)`, you can do this:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv){
    std::cout << "Value: ";
    MyPrint(12, std::cout) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "there is no reason not to pass in the ostream by reference". Some folks don't like non-const reference parameters. I disagree with them, but I wouldn't say there is "no reason" for their preference.

Comment: I don't see how a non-const pointer would be preferable to a non-const reference in any sane coding standard.

Comment: Google says "References can be confusing, as they have value syntax but pointer semantics" (http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml?showone=Reference_Arguments#Reference_Arguments). I think they mean that pass-by-value and pass-by-reference look the same at the call site, so they think code is more readable if readers can assume that anything which looks like a pass-by-value, leaves the value unmodified. And as the saying goes, Google is insane like a fox. It does have some slightly old-fashioned attitudes to C++, but I think not irrational.

Comment: The standard `operator<<` notation takes the `std::ostream` by reference as an input; since this guy is attempting to emulate ostream's functionality, it would be better to match the syntax rather than passing a reference. Plus, he's returning a reference to the dereferenced pointer!

If you used a pointer, you would have to call something like
`MyPrint(12, &(std::cout << "Value:") );`
which is just awkward. You're passing a pointer to a temporary object.

Comment: "The standard operator<< notation takes the std::ostream by reference as an input". Yes, Google notes "necessary for some applications" as a "Con" of their "no non-const reference" rule. This is among the reasons I disagree with the rule: it's a pretty killer "Con" :-)

Answer (score 0):

After changing the pointer to a reference, you can do this:

```
#include <iostream>

std::ostream& MyPrint(int val, std::ostream& out) {
    out << val;
    return out;
}

int main(int, char**) {
    MyPrint(11, std::cout << "Value: ") << std::endl; 

    return 0;
}
```

The syntax for `MyPrint` is essentially that of an unrolled `operator<<` but with an extra argument.

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be solved this way:

[image: my_answer]

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34760664)

Answer (score 0):

Since C++11, chaining a function returning a reference to an ostream with another ostream is ill-formed. For e.g., see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49110287/1047213).

The reason is because since C++11, there is no implicit conversion of an ostream to a `void *`.

Answer (score -1):

In your case the answer is obviously:

```
 std::cout << "Value: " << 12 << std::endl;
```

If that isn't good enough, please explain what output you want to see.

Comment: The example is obviously simplified, and shows the user wants to understand how to chain stream operations.

Comment: Unlike many people round here, I don't have the happy facility of understanding the "obvious" unasked question - I like to have things spelled out.

Comment: I think you should chage your icon to a grumpy faced starfish :-(

Comment: If you can find me one, I'll happily use it.