# ostream chaining, output order

Tags: c++, iostream, chaining

I have a function that takes an `ostream` reference as an argument, writes some data to the stream, and then returns a reference to that same stream, like so:

```
#include <iostream>

std::ostream& print( std::ostream& os ) {
  os << " How are you?" << std::endl;
  return os;
}

int main() {
  std::cout << "Hello, world!" << print( std::cout ) << std::endl;
}
```

The output of this code is:

```
 How are you?
Hello, world!0x601288
```

However, if I separate the chaining expressions into two statements, like this

```
int main() {
  std::cout << "Hello, world!";
  std::cout << print( std::cout ) << std::endl;
}
```

then I at least get the proper order in the output, but still get a hex value:

```
Hello, world! How are you?
0x600ec8
```

I would like to understand what's going on here. Does a normal function take precedence over `operator<<`, and that's why the output order reverses? What is the proper way to write a function that inserts data into an `ostream` but that can also chain with `operator<<`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The behavior of your code is *unspecified* as per the C++ Standard.

### Explanation

The following (I removed `std::endl` for simplicity)

```
std::cout << "Hello, world!" << print( std::cout );
```

is equivalent to this:

```
operator<<(operator<<(std::cout, "Hello, World!"), print(std::cout));
```

which is a function call, passing two arguments:

- First argument is : `operator<<(std::cout, "Hello, World!")`
- Second argument is :  `print(std::cout)`

Now, the Standard doesn't specify the order in which arguments are evaluated. It is *unspecified*. But your compiler seems to evaluate the second argument first, that is why it prints *"How are you?"* first, evaluating the second argument to a value of type `std::ostream&` which then gets passed to the call shown above (that value is the object `std::cout` itself).

### Why hexadecimal output?

You get hexadecimal output because the second argument evaluates to `std::cout`, which is being printed as hexadecimal number, because `std::cout` implicitly converts into pointer value of `void*` type, which is why it is printed as hexadecimal number.

Try this:

```
void const *pointer = std::cout; //implicitly converts into pointer type!
std::cout << std::cout << std::endl;
std::cout << pointer << std::endl;
```

It will print the same value for both. For example, this example at [ideone](http://ideone.com/GwsjQ) prints this:

```
0x804a044
0x804a044
```

Also note that I didn't use *explicit* cast; rather `std::cout` is *implicitly* converted into pointer type.

Hope that helps.

---

> What is the proper way to write a function that inserts data into an `ostream` but that can also chain with `operator<<`?

When it depends on what you mean by chaining? Obviously, the following wouldn't work (as explained above):

```
std::cout << X << print(std::cout) << Y << Z; //unspecified behaviour!
```

No matter how you write `print()`.

However this is well-defined:

```
print(std::cout) << X << Y << Z; //well-defined behaviour!
```

Comment: Doesn't answer "What is the proper way to write a function that inserts data into an ostream but that can also chain with `operator<<`?"

Comment: @Mr.Anubis: I was having dinner in between :P

Answer (score 3):

The reason is that your print() function will be evaluated before the rest of the statement and return a reference to cout which is then actually printed as a pointer (cout << cout). This order of evaluation is actually unspecified behavior, but seems to be the case with your compiler.

As for defining a stream aware "function" that actually has defined behavior with the same functionality, this would work;

```
#include <iostream>

template <class charT, class traits>
  std::basic_ostream<charT,traits>& print ( std::basic_ostream<charT,traits>& os )
{
        os << " How are you?" << std::endl;
        return os;
}

int main() {
  std::cout << "Hello, world!" << print << std::endl;
}
```

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/621548/477878) for a little more detail on what "unspecified" actually means in this case.

Answer (score 3):

## Hexadecimal Output

Before C++11, the class `std::ostream` has a conversion function to `void*`. Since your `print` function returns `std::ostream&`, when evaluating `std::cout << print(...)`, the returned `std::ostream` lvalue will be implicitly converted to `void*` and then be outputted as a pointer value. This is why there is a hexadecimal output.

Since C++11, this conversion function [is replaced](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32169019/5376789) by an **explicit** conversion function to `bool`, so trying to output an `std::ostream` object becomes ill-formed.

## Evaluation Order

Before C++17, overloaded operator is considered a function call for analyzing evaluation order, and evaluation order of different arguments of a function call is unspecified. So it is not strange that the `print` function is evaluated firstly, which causes  `How are you?` is outputted firstly.

Since C++17, the evaluation order of operands of operator `<<` is strictly from left to right, and operands of overloaded operator share the same evaluation order as those of the bulit-in one (see more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38501596/5376789)). So your program will always get the output (assume `print` returns something able to be outputted)

```
Hello, world! How are you?
something returned by print
```

[LIVE EXAMPLE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/H6xMF5nliFaJjFPZ)

Answer (score 1):

In your statement `std::cout << "Hello, world!" << print( std::cout ) << std::endl` it's undefined whether `std::cout << "Hello, world!"` happens before or after `print( std::cout )`. That's why the order may not be what you expect.

The hex value comes from the fact that you're also doing `std::cout << std::cout` (`print` returns `std::cout` which is fed into the `<<` chain). The right hand `std::cout` is converted to a `void *` and that's printed to the output.

Answer (score 1):

This would work, to combine `print` with `<<` and control the order:

```
print( std::cout << "Hello, world!" ) << std::endl;
```

Or, if you want a function that's called with `<<`, see Joachim's answer.