# Overloaded chained operator<< buffering output

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have a simple class `LinkedList` with overloaded stream insertion and indexing operators.

**LinkedList.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
#include <ostream>

namespace linkedlist
{
    class LinkedList
    {
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const LinkedList&);

        struct Node;
        Node *head;
        int n;

        struct Node
        {
            double data;
            Node *next;

            Node(double data) : data(data), next(nullptr) {} 
        };

    public:
        LinkedList() = default;
        ~LinkedList();

    public:
        LinkedList& add(double);
        const double& operator[](int index) const;
        double& operator[](int index);
    };
}
```

**LinkedList.cpp**

```
#include "LinkedList.h"

namespace linkedlist
{
    LinkedList::~LinkedList()
    {
        while (head)
        {
            Node *toDelete = head;
            head = head->next;
            delete toDelete;
        }

        head = nullptr;
    }

    LinkedList& LinkedList::add(double data)
    {
        Node *newNode = new Node(data);

        if (head == nullptr)
            head = newNode;

        else 
        {
            Node *temp = head; 

            while (temp->next)
            {
                temp = temp->next;
            }
            temp->next = newNode; 
        }

        n++;
        return *this;
    }

    const double& LinkedList::operator[](int index) const
    {
        Node *temp = head;

        while (--index)
            temp = temp->next;

        return temp->data;
    }

    double& LinkedList::operator[](int index)
    {
        Node *temp = head;

        while (index-- > 0)
            temp = temp->next;

        return temp->data;
    }


    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const LinkedList& list)
    {
        for (LinkedList::Node *temp = list.head; temp != nullptr; temp = temp->next)
            stream << temp->data << " ";

        return stream;
    }

}
```

Both operator functions are tested and are working correctly.

However, when stepping into the **last line** of the main function

```
int main()
{
    LinkedList A;
    A.add(3).add(2).add(5).add(7);

//  cout << A << endl;     // works!
//  cout << A[0] << endl;  // works!
    cout << A[0] << " " << A[1] << " " << A[2] << " " << A[3] << " " << endl;   
}
```

I noticed a strange behavior of  the stream insertion operator.

Since the associativity of the operator doesn't change even when it is overloaded, I expected the calls to `operator[]` to be executed from left to right and after each one an element to be printed and `ostream` reference returned (to allow proper chaining of the operator).

Instead, operators were called from the right-most one

[image: first visit to the operator[]]

And after the four consecutive calls to the `operator[]` the execution went to the `ostream` class and the elements were printed to the console.

Is this some sort of buffering? Why are chained `<<` operators behaving like this?

Comment: The order of evaluation is unspecified.  See, for example, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8931249/ostream-chaining-output-order).

Comment: Associativity applies to operators, not their operands.

Comment: @G.M. the order of evaluation for the `A[?]` is unspecified, but the `operator<<` will be called from left to right, no?

Comment: @tobi303 Yes, I was referring specifically to the order in which the various calls to `operator[]` were evaluated.  Sorry, should've been more careful with my wording in the comment.