# C++ Passing By Reference Not Changing Argument

Tags: c++

I've been staring at this for about an hour and I honestly have no idea what I'm missing.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void callChain();

double chain(int, int &, int &);

int main()
{
    callChain();
}

void callChain() {
    int totalInches = 53;
    int feet;
    int inches;

    cout << "\nTesting chain for 53 inches: \nExpected result: 15.46 feet: 4 inches: 5" << endl;
    cout << "Actual result: " << chain(totalInches, feet, inches) << " feet: " << feet << " inches: " << inches << endl;
}

double chain(int totalInches, int &feet, int &inches) {
    feet = totalInches / 12;
    inches = totalInches % 12;

    return (feet) * 3.49 + (inches) * .30;
}
```

The return is correct, so obviously the function is working, but for the life of me I can't figure out why feet and inches aren't changing. Everything is spelled right, I have all my ampersands, but for some reason, the display is showing feet as 8 and inches as 7. I have no idea where those numbers are even coming from.

Comment: The order things happens in your output is not specified. You don't know in which order the `feet`, `inches` and the `chain()` function call will be evaluated.

Comment: Check this question and its answers: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8931249/5958455

Comment: And just to show how indeterminate things can be, I pasted your code verbatim into jdoodle for g++ 14 GCC 7.20 at got the answers you expected to have. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The evaluation order is unspecified in the ISO C++ standard, according to [ostream chaining, output order](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8931249/5958455)

To ensure the function is called before those variables are accessed, separate the output chain:

```
cout << "Actual result: " << chain(totalInches, feet, inches);
cout << " feet: " << feet << " inches: " << inches << endl;
```

Comment: Since C++17, the evaluation order is strictly from left to right. I have also added a late answer to the question you linked.

Answer (score 5):

Remember that `<<` is syntatic sugar for a function call and the order of evaluation of these functions is not necessarily in the order that you think it is. In fact C++ doesn't actually specify the order. So the final parts of you second `cout` are printing out the starting values of `feet` and `inches`.

Call `chain(totalInches, feet, inches)` in an intermediate step before the second `cout`, perhaps even in this way (Acknowledge @DavidSchwartz):

```
cout << "Actual result: " << chain(totalInches, feet, inches);
cout << " feet: " << feet << " inches: " << inches << endl;
```

Comment: Or just: `cout << "Actual result: " << chain(totalInches, feet, inches); cout  << " feet: " << feet << " inches: " << inches << endl;`

Answer (score 0):

Just for better illustration of the answers given so far (giving some more details):

`std::cout << x` is syntactic sugar for `operator<<(std::cout, x)`; as `operator<<` returns its first argument, `std::cout << x << y;` gets:

```
operator<<(operator<<(std::cout, x), y);
```

Obviously, the first argument to the outer call will be evaluated (e. g. the inner call executed) before the the outer call actually is performed – and this is where any guarantees already end, i. e. as order of argument evaluation is unspecified, the compiler is quite well allowed to evaluate `y` before the call to the inner operator – including the evaluation of the latter's arguments!

```
operator<<(operator<<(std::cout, f(x)), x);
```

Similarly now, the only guarantees here are that `f(x)` is called before the inner operator is called and the inner operator being called before the outer one; still, the raw `x` can be evaluated at very first...

Obviously, your compiler starts evaluating the arguments from last to first, most likely due to the calling convention in use (quite likely [`cdecl`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#cdecl); on Windows possibly `stdcall`)...

The change in the accepted answer introduces a sequence point between the function calls (old, pre-C++11 wording), which ensures that all effects of the previous call are completed before the call to the next function, i. e. (using new C++11 wording):

```
operator<<(std::cout, f(x)); // is sequenced  b e f o r e  next line
operator<<(std::cout, x);    // is sequenced  a f t e r  previous line
```