# friend, template, namespace

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, friend

I want to have a templated friend function. However, I do not know how to make it works in the same way for no templated function.
Here is a sample code

```
#include <iostream>

namespace ns{
struct Obj {
    friend void foo(Obj){std::cout << "no problem" << std::endl;}

    template<typename T>
    friend void bar(Obj){std::cout << "problem" << std::endl;}
};
}

int main() {
    ns::Obj obj;
    foo(obj); // Compile
    bar<int>(obj); // Not compile
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/991518/c-how-do-i-call-a-friend-template-function-defined-inside-a-class

Comment: @NathanOliver It's unfortunate which answer is accepted there... Faisal's answer is great, but I'd be more inclined to close that one as a dupe of this one.

Comment: @Barry Yes it is.  I commented a while back but the user never responded.

Comment: @Barry We could delete that one answer and then dupe close or ask a mod to merge.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Before C++20, you need to teach the compiler that `bar` is the name of a template so that it knows that `<` starts a template argument list and is not the less-than operator:

```
template<char> void bar() = delete;

int main() {
    ns::Obj obj;
    foo(obj); // Compile
    bar<int>(obj); // Now compiles too
    return 0;
}
```

Note that all the `bar` overload has to do is to *be a function template*. The signature doesn't matter as long as it's not so good as to interfere with the overload resolution; `()` is a good choice because by definition we are passing at least one argument, so a function template taking no parameters can never be viable.

Alternatively, you can redesign `bar` to deduce `T` from a tag argument:

```
template<class T>
struct type {};

namespace ns{
struct Obj {    
    // ...

    template<typename T>
    friend void bar(Obj, type<T>) { /* ... */ }
};
}
// ...

bar(obj, type<int>()); // OK
```

---

In C++20, the compiler will assume that `bar` names a template when it sees the `<` and name lookup finds nothing, so your code will *just work*.

Comment: I tried your solution, but it fails : here is the sample :
https://wandbox.org/permlink/1u8lrhFZ7ECzd43y

Comment: @AntoineMorrier it does as long as you make the class version return void: https://wandbox.org/permlink/ZwOwa0ks034CKcju

Answer (score 4):

The straightforward approach would be to add a forward declaration and let the function be located using qualified lookup:

```
namespace ns{
struct Obj;

void foo(Obj);

template<typename T>
void bar(Obj);

struct Obj {
    friend void foo(Obj){std::cout << "no problem" << std::endl;}

    template<typename T>
    friend void bar(Obj){std::cout << "problem " << std::endl;}
};
} // namespace ns

int main() {
    ns::Obj obj;
    ns::foo(obj); // Ok
    ns::bar<int>(obj); // Ok
    return 0;
}
```